# Insertar anuncios de adwords en mi web y extraer una variable

Tags: php, javascript, adword

Estoy empezando con esto de adwords y no tengo ni idea de como va. Resulta que necesito implementar un anuncio en mi web. La página esta lista ya he agregado la URL de mi web en mi Google adwords. El problema es que lo que necesito no es un banner, lo que quiero es extraer del anuncio el titulo e integrarlo como H1 y que este se muestre en la web. Es posible eso?

pensaba que usando `$_GET`, como por ejemplo:

```
<?php

$title = $_GET['ID_DE_LA_URL'];

echo '< h1>' . $title . '< /h1>';

?>
```

Podria extraer datos de la URL y de ahi sacar lo que necesito, pero no es tan sencillo y la verdad que despues de dos dias intensos informandome, no encuentro nada al respecto.

Alguien me podria explicar o pasarme alguna URL donde pueda sacar algo en claro?

Muchas Gracias